# What is the appearance of Hoor?

Tags: jannah

I have heard many things about **Hoor**. Some from Qur’an and some from Hadith.

From Qur'an

> Hoor's eyes are like Deer's eye.

*"sorry I don't know surah name and ayat's number."*

I can understand a little by this ayat and more with other information but these are only parts which I know. I don't know it in details.

Over all I know only parts of complete detail so I want to know it with reference of ayat or hadith.

Comment: This really needs to be asked as separate questions.

Comment: @Murtaza A,Please ask your second question about seeing hoors in a separate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 14 features for Hoor in Quran:

**1) Purity and cleanliness:**

> - "...And they will have therein purified spouses, and they will abide therein eternally...."(Surat Al-Baqarah,verse25)
> - "...and purified spouses and approval from Allah..."(Surat 'Āli `Imrān,verse15)
> - "...For them therein are purified spouses..."(Surat An-Nisā',verse57)

**2) Coarse black eyes:**

> - "Thus. And We will marry them to fair women with large, [beautiful] eyes."(Surat Ad-Dukhān,verse54)
> - "...and We will marry them to fair women with large, [beautiful] eyes."(Surat Aţ-Ţūr,verse20)

**3) Being covered and hidden:**

> "And [for them are] fair women with large, [beautiful] eyes;The
>   likenesses of pearls well-protected"(Surat Al-Wāqi`ah,verse22-23)

Means:They are completely covered from others eyes,no hand reach them over,and no eyes have fallen on them except for their spouses.(Nemune interpretation,v:23,p:215 )

**4) Only love their spouses and are charm:**

> - "In them are women limiting [their] glances, untouched before them by man or jinni"(Surat Ar-Raĥmān,verse56)
> - "And with them will be women limiting [their] glances, with large, [beautiful] eyes"(Surat Aş-Şāffāt,verse48)

**5) Are virgin:**

> - "...untouched before them by man or jinni"(Surat Ar-Raĥmān,verse56)
> - "Untouched before them by man or jinni"(Surat Ar-Raĥmān,verse74)

**6) They are like ruby and coral:**

> "As if they were rubies and coral."(Surat Ar-Raĥmān,verse58)

Means:They are as purity and radiance of "ruby" and as beautiful white of "corals" that this combination gives them the best color.

**7) They have good character and good face:**

> "In them are good and beautiful women"(Surat Ar-Raĥmān,verse70)

**8) Only belong to their spouses:**

> "Fair ones reserved in pavilions"(Surat Ar-Raĥmān,verse72)

Means:They are safe from strangers and just their spouses watch them.

**9)Have pure body with elegance:**

> "As if they were [delicate] eggs, well-protected."(Surat
>   Aş-Şāffāt,verse49)

Means: The intensity of their purity and elegance of their body, is such as white egg that no man has touched it nor dust sits on, but is hidden under the wing of hen.

**10) Peer to their spouses:**

> "And with them will be women limiting [their] glances and of equal
>   age."(Surat Şād,verse52)

**11) Have new creation:**

> "Indeed, We have produced the women of Paradise in a [new]
>   creation"(Surat Al-Wāqi`ah,verse35)

Means: They have a new creation which God has given them so that they won't become old and disable.

**12) Will be always virgin:**

> "And made them virgins"(Surat Al-Wāqi`ah,verse36)

**13) Are eloquent and oratorical:**

> "Devoted [to their husbands] and of equal age"(Surat
>   Al-Wāqi`ah,verse37)

**14) Are young women:**

> "And full-breasted [companions] of equal age"(Surat An-Naba',verse33)

At the end Hoors are in heaven and are rewarded to righteous.